# Finding unique permutations of a list in gprolog

Tags: prolog

I am working on a problem for homework.  I am trying to get all the unique permutations of 0 and 1 where the number of 0s and 1s is passed in to binaryLists/3.  I have a set of rules that will get the permutations, but I get a large number of duplicates as permutation/2 treats each 0 and 1 as unique.  I feel like I need to put a cut somewhere, but I don't really understand cuts and I'm not sure how to think about this.  My code is as follows:

```
binaryLists(0, 0, R).
binaryLists(Z, O, R) :-
   Z >= 0, O >= 0,
   generateZero(Z, Lz),
   generateOne(O, Lo),
   append(Lz, Lo, Tmp),
   permutation(Tmp, R).

generateZero(0, R) :-
   R = [].
generateZero(Z, R) :-
    Z > 0,
    Y is Z - 1,
    generateZero(Y, Tmp),
    append(Tmp, [0], R).

generateOne(0, R) :-
   R = [].
generateOne(Z, R) :-
   Z > 0,
   Y is Z - 1,
   generateOne(Y, Tmp),
   append(Tmp, [1], R).
```

The result of this will give many duplicates of the same list (e.g. [1, 0, 0, 0]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cut won't help you here. It's a common Prolog beginner mistake to make rules overly complex and procedural, then try to fix things with cuts.

Here are some hints. You don't need `append/3`, `permutation/2`, and you don't need a 0/1 list generator.

Your first rule is on the right track, but has a flaw. You have the singleton `R`. You're trying to say that a list with 0 zeroes, and 0 ones, should be an empty list. So just say that:

```
binaryList(0, 0, []).
```

Now you can define two more rules which give the conditions for when the resulting list should start with a 1 and when it should start with a 0. Those are the only two additional rules you need:

```
binaryList(Zeroes, Ones, [0|R]) :-
    Zeroes > 0,
    ...  % What goes here?
    binaryList(..., Ones, R).  % What goes in place of ...?

binaryList(Zeroes, Ones, [1|R]) :-
    Ones > 0,
    ...  % What goes here?
    binaryList(Zeroes, ..., R).  % What goes in place of ...?
```

Once you create the proper rules in Prolog that define what makes a valid list, then Prolog will do the work for you in terms of exploring all of the possible solutions that satisfy the rules. That's how you get all of the permutations. The permutations are unique because the rules are non-overlapping in their solutions and ensure that each solution is different.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you for the help.  I'm still having trouble putting myself into the right mindset to program in prolog so I appreciate the walkthrough.